Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
I am working on spring boot web application, earlier the code was implemented to connect with the alibaba cloud service, now we are migrating it to AWS cloud service. We have done the changes but it is throwing errors.
2024-04-22 22:36:32 IST [http-nio-8080-exec-2] WARN  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions(SqlExceptionHelper.java:137) 
 SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null 
2024-04-22 22:36:32 IST [http-nio-8080-exec-2] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions(SqlExceptionHelper.java:142) 
 Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.) 
2024-04-22 22:36:32 IST [http-nio-8080-exec-2] WARN  org.apache.shiro.authc.AbstractAuthenticator - org.apache.shiro.authc.AbstractAuthenticator.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticator.java:216) 
 Authentication failed for token submission [com.sharing.shiro.common.LoginToken - admin, rememberMe=false (0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1)].  Possible unexpected error? (Typical or expected login exceptions should extend from AuthenticationException). 
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:577) ~[spring-orm-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:377) ~[spring-tx-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:461) ~[spring-tx-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:277) ~[spring-tx-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sharing.shiro.service.LoginService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$58ed6fc9.loginByAgencyUser(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.sharing.shiro.common.realm.AgencyUserReam.doGetAuthenticationInfo(AgencyUserReam.java:40) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.apache.shiro.realm.AuthenticatingRealm.getAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticatingRealm.java:571) ~[shiro-core-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.ModularRealmAuthenticator.doSingleRealmAuthentication(ModularRealmAuthenticator.java:180) ~[shiro-core-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at com.sharing.shiro.common.realm.MyModularRealmAuthenticator.doAuthenticate(MyModularRealmAuthenticator.java:85) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.apache.shiro.authc.AbstractAuthenticator.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticator.java:198) [shiro-core-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.apache.shiro.mgt.AuthenticatingSecurityManager.authenticate(AuthenticatingSecurityManager.java:106) [shiro-core-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager.login(DefaultSecurityManager.java:275) [shiro-core-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.login(DelegatingSubject.java:260) [shiro-core-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at com.sharing.web.controller.IndexController.login(IndexController.java:124) [classes/:?]
    at com.sharing.web.controller.IndexController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$77552ad5.invoke(<generated>) [classes/:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) [spring-core-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:652) [spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sharing.web.controller.IndexController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fd542c3f.login(<generated>) [classes/:?]
    at com.sharing.web.controller.IndexController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$77552ad5.invoke(<generated>) [classes/:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) [spring-core-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:721) [spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:139) [spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656) [spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sharing.web.controller.IndexController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b4ea459a.login(<generated>) [classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_401]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_401]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_401]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_401]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:220) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) [spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) [spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) [spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) [spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) [spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) [spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:515) [servlet-api.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:583) [servlet-api.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:212) [catalina.jar:8.5.100]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:156) [catalina.jar:8.5.100]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.5.100]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:181) [catalina.jar:8.5.100]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:156) [catalina.jar:8.5.100]
    at com.sharing.common.language.ZHHKFilter.doFilter(ZHHKFilter.java:31) [classes/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:181) [catalina.jar:8.5.100]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:156) [catalina.jar:8.5.100]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61) [shiro-web-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108) [shiro-web-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137) [shiro-web-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125) [shiro-web-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66) [shiro-web-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449) [shiro-web-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365) [shiro-web-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90) [shiro-core-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83) [shiro-core-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:387) [shiro-core-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362) [shiro-web-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125) [shiro-web-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:181) [catalina.jar:8.5.100]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:156) [catalina.jar:8.5.100]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:181) [catalina.jar:8.5.100]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:156) [catalina.jar:8.5.100]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:168) [catalina.jar:8.5.100]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) [catalina.jar:8.5.100]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:483) [catalina.jar:8.5.100]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130) [catalina.jar:8.5.100]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) [catalina.jar:8.5.100]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:679) [catalina.jar:8.5.100]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [catalina.jar:8.5.100]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:346) [catalina.jar:8.5.100]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:617) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.100]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.100]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:934) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.100]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1690) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.100]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.100]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-util.jar:8.5.100]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-util.jar:8.5.100]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) [tomcat-util.jar:8.5.100]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) [?:1.8.0_401]
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:136) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getConnectionForTransactionManagement(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:254) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:262) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:236) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.beginTransaction(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:452) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:535) ~[spring-orm-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 92 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2385) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.ap

I have done the changes in the hibernate.cfg.xml, spring-code.xml and spring-hibernate.xml files as per the AWS configuration. Also i have tested the connection over the mysql workbench and it is working fine there but issue is with the web application which i am running with tomcat local server.

The log indicates a communication link failure.
A firewall or slow connectivity are possible causes of the link failures in these circumstances.
Can you check if you have a good connection to the AWS environment from the host environment for the spring boot applications?

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
